is there a way to quickly change to a particular set of wallpapers (background images) on multiple monitors on macOS
I have a multi-monitor setup.  Sometimes I stream writing code from my Mac.  When I do, I have a particular configuration of background images that I like to use, both:

for a consistent Brand™ Image
to make it easier to identify which monitor is "live" and which one is holding private stuff that only I can see

When I'm streaming, I want to have a specific wallpaper on a specific monitor, and when I'm not streaming, I want to put those images back to a different configuration.  However, I have two problems with this:

I have found that as I open and close my laptop lid, plug in my external monitor, activate my virtual streaming display, etc, macOS gets confused and swaps around the images sometimes, making it hard to put stuff back.
locating the images that I want to use in the somewhat jumbled "Wallpaper" pref pane, which has no search or even folder organization that I can see, takes time and is annoying.

Is there an app or a command-line utility for this that would let me save & restore wallpaper configurations, or maybe just some more streamlined way to use the wallpapers prefpane to select things quickly, out of the big pile of Apple stuff and "Pictures" and "Photos" and dynamic wallpapers and etc?
